# How to get the clientid of the control which is placed inside the Edit item template of the gridview in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview

i  to get the clientid of the control which is placed inside the Edit item template of the gridview in javascript without going to the server side code..

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FromDate" SortExpression="FromDate">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="FromDate" runat="server" Text='<%#((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FromDate")).ToShortDateString()%>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="ID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="ApproveLeaveID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ApproveLeaveID") %>' />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidLevel3" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Level3ManagerACENumber") %>' />

                                     </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFDate" runat="server" Text='<%#((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FromDate")).ToShortDateString()%>'>
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="ID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="ApproveLeaveID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ApproveLeaveID") %>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidLevel3" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Level3ManagerACENumber") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a onclick="showCalendarControl(3,<%# Container.ItemIndex %>)">
                                        <img id="img3" runat="server" alt="Clock" src="../Images/clock_add.png" style="border: none" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ToDate" SortExpression="ToDate">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ToDate" runat="server" Text='<%#((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ToDate")).ToShortDateString()%>'>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTDate" runat="server" Text='<%#((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ToDate")).ToShortDateString()%>'>
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a onclick="showCalendarControl(4,<%# Container.ItemIndex %>)">
                                        <img id="img4" runat="server" alt="Clock" src="../Images/clock_add.png" style="border: none" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is my java script:

```
 function showCalendarControl(ControlNo,index) {
var textField;
if(ControlNo==1)
{
textField=document.getElementById('<%=txtFromDate.ClientID%>');
}
else
{
textField=document.getElementById('<%=txtToDate.ClientID%>');
}
if(ControlNo==3)
{
    textField=document.getElementsByClassName('txtFDate')[index];
}
if(ControlNo==4)
{
    textField=document.getElementsByClassName('txtTDate')[index];
}

  calendarControl.show(textField);
}
```

first two textbox(txtFromDate,txtToDate) is for the not in the grid control...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the elements in the `ItemDataBound` event of the grid (using FindControl), and then pass the ClientID of the textbox as a parameter to `showCalendarControl`:

```
TextBox txtFDate = e.Item.FindControl("txtFDate") as TextBox;
TextBox txtTDate = e.Item.FindControl("txtTDate") as TextBox;
HtmlAnchor link = e.Item.FindControl("aLink") as HtmlAnchor;

if (txtTDate != null && txtFDate != null && link != null)
{
   link.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("showCalendarControl({0}, '{1}', '{2}')", 4, txtFDate.ClientID, txtTDate.ClientID);
}
```

(you'll also need to add an ID and a `runat="server"` to your link. I'm also assuming txtFDate is declared in your EditTemplate although it's not there. The ControlNo parameter could be a data key instead of a constant as in the example, it's not really clear what it is)

Then, in your function, use the clientID parameters to get the textboxes:

```
function showCalendarControl(ControlNo, txtFDateClientID, txtTDateClientID) {
var textField;
if(ControlNo==3)
{
textField=document.getElementById(txtFDateClientID);
}
if(ControlNo==4)
{
textField=document.getElementById(txtTDateClientID);
}
  calendarControl.show(textField);
}
```

Comment: The same as you did before, but this time use the client ID parameters to get the right textboxes (example added).

Comment: This is correct a to pass in the design mode  <a onclick="showCalendarControl(3)" runat="server">
                                            <img id="img3" runat="server" alt="Clock" src="../Images/clock_add.png" style="border: none" /></a>

Comment: Can't say that I really understood your last comment. But the idea in my suggestion is that you add the onclick event in the server event `OnItemDataBound` instead of declaring it inline.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every control should have unique server ID. So server side controls which are placed inside template are rendered multiple times with different auto generated ids based on ID you've specified in the template. You can easily see it if you will have a look on the generated html. Therefore your js code is accessing only the html element with hardcoded id. As I guess it is placed in the first row.

Simple solution is to describe your text box in a following way

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTDate" runat="server" CssClass="txtTDate" Text='<%#((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ToDate")).ToShortDateString()%>'>
                                    </asp:TextBox>
```

Then modify the js function in the following way :

```
function showCalendarControl(ControlNo, index) {
var textField;
if(ControlNo==3)
{
    textField=document.getElementsByClassName('txtFDate')[index];
}
if(ControlNo==4)
{
    textField=document.getElementsByClassName('txtTDate')[index];
}
  calendarControl.show(textField);
}
```

And modify your link as the following :

```
<a onclick="showCalendarControl(4, <%# Container.DataItemIndex %>)">
```

**Updated the answer** 
`DataItemContainer` has `DataItemIndex` property which has to be used in this case.

Comment: i am geting error in the design mode.'System.Web.UI.IDataItemContainer' does not contain a definition for 'ItemIndex'

Comment: this area <a onclick="showCalendarControl(4, <%# Container.ItemIndex %>)">

Comment: sorry. I did not know which container are you using - this is an exmple for asp:Repeater control. I'll update the answer in couple of minutes.

Comment: its not working when i click the image button no action is performed

Comment: can you just put something like alert(ControlNo + ' ' + index) at the beginning of showCalendarControl function so we can ensure that parameters are passed correctly ?

Comment: You can also put a alert('element retrieved') before calendarControl.show(textField); so we can localize the problem